# Make legend for scale_fill_continuous continuous scale instead of discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the function of `scale_fill_gradientn()` which normally should produce a continuous scale as the legend but somehow if I use the following code attached below the outcome produces a legend with boxes of colours as discrete values

```
  ggplot(aes(x=grouping,y=person,fill=score)) + 
  geom_tile(stat = "identity",position = "identity",colour="black",size=1) + 
  facet_grid(family~functional,switch = "y") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white","orange","red"),
    limits=c(0,100),breaks = c(0,50,100),labels=c("min","mid","max"),
    guide = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal",title.position = "bottom")) +
    labs(fill = "Average Percentage")
```

[image]

I notice that as long as I remove the `guide` argument from the `scale_fill_gradientn()` function it would give me back a continuous scale i.e.

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white","orange","red"),
    limits=c(0,100),breaks = c(0,50,100),labels=c("min","mid","max"))
```

[image]

But then my question would be why does this occur and if I have to refrain from using the `guide` argument how can I add a black border around the scale (like the picture above with the discrete colour boxes) as well as adjust the positioning of the title and labels e.g. put the legend title below the colour bar and labels above the colour bar? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a working code. Your current ggplot function does not call on a data. Also, please provide an example of the dataset, specifically what is the structure of the data, especially for the variable 'score'.

Comment: Seconding Adam's comment, please share reproducible minimal sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential solution using the [palmer penguins dataset](https://allisonhorst.github.io/palmerpenguins/) as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = body_mass_g, y = bill_length_mm, fill = flipper_length_mm)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "orange", "red"),
                       limits = c(170, 240), breaks = c(180, 205, 235),
                       labels = c("min", "mid", "max"),
                       guide = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal",
                                            title.position = "bottom"))
```

[image]

```r
penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = body_mass_g, y = bill_length_mm, fill = flipper_length_mm)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "orange", "red"),
                       limits = c(170, 240), breaks = c(180, 205, 235),
                       labels = c("min", "mid", "max"),
                       guide = guide_colourbar(direction = "horizontal",
                                               title.position = "bottom"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: For everyone's sake, use `guide_colourbar` instead of `guide_legend` in `scale_fill_gradientn`.